# Estimate individual income based on membership to a bucket

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm not sure the title gives an accurate description but the problem is straightforward:

Let's say I have 10 people with a total income of 1000. I always know the total number of people and total income. I don't know how much any of them makes, but I can split them in buckets:

- high income bucket
- medium income bucket
- low income bucket

I know how many people are in each bucket.

How can I assign `weights` to these buckets and then calculate an income (an estimate) for each individual, based on the bucket (therefore the `weight` of the bucket) which they belong to.

Everyone in the `High bucket` would have the same individual estimated income, which would be more than the individual income of the ones in the `Medium bucket`. How much more... this is where the `weight` offset should come into play.

Thank you :)

Comment: Do we see the incomes as random variables? Do we know anything of their distribution?

Comment: @MattiP. I see the incomes as estimations. We don't know anything about their distribution.

Basically everyone in the High bucket would have the same estimated income, which would be more than the income of the ones in the Medium bucket. How much more... this is where the weight offset should come into play.

Comment: So what numbers **do** you know? Do you know the limit values of each bucket? Do you know how many people there are in each bucket?

Comment: @MattiP. thank you for helping me clarify the question. I edited it. I know:

Total Income; total number of people; number of people in each bucket.

Comment: Now we can perhaps start jotting down some equations. We know the total number of people, which is
$$
n_l + n_m + n_h
$$
Let's then assume that the average income in each bucket is $\mu_l, \mu_m$ and $\mu_h$, respectively. Now we know that the sum of all the incomes is
$$
\mu_l n_l + \mu_m n_m + \mu_h n_h = 1~000
$$